# ImageMagick:convert unable to crop image

Tags: macos, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I use the following command to crop big image:

```
convert hq.jpg -crop 512x512 -set filename:tile "%[fx:page.x/512]-%[fx:page.y/512]" "hq/%[filename:tile].jpg"
```

But get the following error:

```
convert: unable to open image `hq/0-0.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2705.
```

my version on MacOS is:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.5-0 Q16 x86_64 2016-07-19 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2016 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype gslib jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr png ps tiff webp x xml zlib
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `mkdir hq` first.

Comment: I've tried this but got the same error

Comment: Try `identify hq.jpg` Then try `touch hq/a` to see if the subdirectory is writeable.

Comment: Did you try those two commands? Can you click `edit` under your question and paste in the result please?

Comment: I can to try the command above some leter. I'll write a result soon

Answer (score 1):

-crop needs an offset which could be your problem e.g. -crop 512x512+0+0

If that does not work I would start off simplifying your code with hardcoded paths and when the crop works start adding the other variables.